# Como quitar línea inferior del Dropdown en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Quiero quitar la línea inferior del Dropdown de Flutter pero no encuentro una opción rápida para esto.

```dart
Expanded(
            child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _opcionSeleccionada,
            items: getOpcionesDropDown(),
            onChanged: (opt) {
              setState(() {
              _opcionSeleccionada = opt; 
              });
            },
          ),
        )
```

Encontre la opción `underline`, esta recibe un  `Widget` pero no se qué `Widget` usar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto usando un `decoration` dentro de un `Container`:

```
Expanded(
            child: DropdownButton(
            underline: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide.none)
              )
            ),
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _opcionSeleccionada,
            items: getOpcionesDropDown(),
            onChanged: (opt) {
              setState(() {
              _opcionSeleccionada = opt; 
              });
            },
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma mas facil y corta es simplemente usar el container sin nada mas

```
 Expanded(
            child: DropdownButton(
            underline: Container(),
            isExpanded: true,
            value: _opcionSeleccionada,
            items: getOpcionesDropDown(),
            onChanged: (opt) {
              setState(() {
              _opcionSeleccionada = opt; 
              });
            },
          ),
        )
```